# CSS button in height full with flexbox

Tags: css

I have a snippet with HTML and CSS code (I use and bootstrap):

```css
.main-section .get-tour {
  height: 75px;
  background: #fcf7f7;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcf7f7 0%, #fcf7f7 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fcf7f7), color-stop(100%, #fcf7f7));
  -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.main-section .get-tour .form-block {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.main-section .get-tour .form-block label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-section .get-tour .form-block i {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #a161e1;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.main-section .get-tour .form-block input {
  background-color: rgba(113, 9, 245, 0.08);
  border: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
}

.main-section .get-tour .form-block button {
  height: 75px;
  background: #f2994a;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css">

<section class="main-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="get-tour">
      <form action="">
        <div class="form-block">

          <label>Where</label>
          <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-block">
          <label>Date</label>
          <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-block">
          <label>Nights</label>
          <i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-block">
          <label>Who</label>
          <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-block">
          <label>Type transport</label>
          <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-block">
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

When I set `height: 75px;` on my button, the whole form rises up, and button does not become in full height of block `get-tour`. How I can fix this issue? I work with flexbox, on class `get-tour` I have property `align-items: center` and all my elements in this block need be vertically center.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `display:flex`,  `justify-content: space-between;` and  `width: inherit;` to form

```
form{
      display:flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: inherit;
      }
```

2. Remove `display:inline-block` and `margin-right:15px;` from  `.main-section .get-tour
   .form-block` class.

```
    .main-section .get-tour .form-block {
      display: inline-block;  /*remove this  */
      margin-right: 15px;     /*remove this  */
    }
```

Optional:

3. If u want u can set the button height as 100%;

```
    .main-section .get-tour .form-block button {
      height: 75px;  /*  If u want u can set the button height as 100%*/
      background: #f2994a;
      border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 21px;
      border: none;
    }
```

**Demo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css">

  <style>
    form {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: inherit;
    }
    
    .main-section .get-tour {
      height: 75px;
      background: #fcf7f7;
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcf7f7 0%, #fcf7f7 100%);
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fcf7f7), color-stop(100%, #fcf7f7));
      -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
      width: 100%;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      border-radius: 4px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding-left: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 35px;
    }
    
    .main-section .get-tour .form-block label {
      display: block;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 300;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      margin-left:25px;
    }
    

    .main-section .get-tour .form-block i {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #a161e1;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    
    .main-section .get-tour .form-block input {
      background-color: rgba(113, 9, 245, 0.08);
      border: none;
      width: 150px;
      height: 35px;
    }
    
    .main-section .get-tour .form-block button {
      height: 75px;
      background: #f2994a;
      border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 21px;
      border: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>



  <section class="main-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="get-tour">
        <form action="">
          <div class="form-block">

            <label>Where</label>
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label> &nbsp;Date</label>
            <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label>&nbsp; &nbsp;Nights</label>
            <i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;Who</label>
            <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label>&nbsp;Type transport</label>
            <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css">

  <style>
    form {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: inherit;
    }
    
    .main-section .get-tour {
      height: 75px;
      background: #fcf7f7;
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcf7f7 0%, #fcf7f7 100%);
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fcf7f7), color-stop(100%, #fcf7f7));
      -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
      width: 100%;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      border-radius: 4px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding-left: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 35px;
    }
    
    .main-section .get-tour .form-block label {
      display: block;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 300;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .one {
      margin-left: 25px;
    }
    
    .two {
      margin-left: 27px;
    }
    
    .three {
      margin-left: 26px;
    }
    
    .four {
      margin-left: 28px;
    }
    
    .five {
      margin-left: 26px;
    }
    
    .main-section .get-tour .form-block i {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #a161e1;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    
    .main-section .get-tour .form-block input {
      background-color: rgba(113, 9, 245, 0.08);
      border: none;
      width: 150px;
      height: 35px;
    }
    
    .main-section .get-tour .form-block button {
      height: 75px;
      background: #f2994a;
      border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 21px;
      border: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>



  <section class="main-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="get-tour">
        <form action="">
          <div class="form-block">

            <label class="one">Where</label>
            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label class="two">Date</label>
            <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label class="three">&nbsp;Nights</label>
            <i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label class="four"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Who</label>
            <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <label class="five"> &nbsp;Type transport</label>
            <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
            <input type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-block">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The width of the button should be to the end. Now you have a padding on end. I need this, please see: https://imgur.com/a/SUgCia4

Comment: @Armaresh S M thanks, all working. But can you help me with labels please? How I can align its how in example: https://imgur.com/a/SUgCia4?

Comment: yes but it's not even. Please see label `Where` he's align is not correctly :( https://imgur.com/a/XXxhLVS

Comment: @MafysGrif  if u r not satisfied u can ask it as a seperate question. if u want to align the label i have to change my full answer i have to use grid or some other concepts. I just answer based on  u r question, in question u haven't mention about label.

Answer (score 0):

### Use grid

Grid is good for this situation, kind of table.

See and tell me if it ok for you :)

In more big screen it look better

```css
.main-section {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.main-section .get-tour {
/*   height: 75px; */
  background: #fcf7f7;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcf7f7 0%, #fcf7f7 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fcf7f7), color-stop(100%, #fcf7f7));
  -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
}

.main-section .get-tour .form-block label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-section .get-tour .form-block i {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #a161e1;
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 2 / 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-section .get-tour .form-block input {
  background-color: rgba(113, 9, 245, 0.08);
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
/*   width: 150px; */
  height: 35px;
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;
}

.main-section .get-tour .search button {
  height: 75px;
  background: #f2994a;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.form-block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 35px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 25px 35px;
  margin: 2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css">

<section class="main-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="get-tour">
      <form class="form" action="">
        <div class="form-block">
          <label>Where</label>
          <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-block">
          <label>Date</label>
          <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-block">
          <label>Nights</label>
          <i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-block">
          <label>Who</label>
          <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-block">
          <label>Type transport</label>
          <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="search">
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```